# Boolean function: prime implicants - disjunctive minimal form

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I applied the Quine-McCluskey method to determine the respective prime implicants for a boolean functions and find a disjunctive minimal form.

We have the function 
\begin{equation*}f(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)=\bar{x}_1x_2(\bar{x}_3\lor x_3\bar{x}_4)\lor x_1(x_3\bar{x}_4\lor x_2)\lor (x_1\bar{x}_2\lor x_2)x_3\lor \bar{x}_1x_2(\bar{x}_3x_4\lor \bar{x}_3\bar{x}_4\lor x_3x_4)\end{equation*}

I have found the prime terms $\bar{x}_1x_2, \ \ x_2x_4, \ \ x_1x_3$.

So the minimal form is 
\begin{equation*}\bar{x}_1x_2\lor x_2x_4\lor x_1x_3\end{equation*}

Is there a way so that we can check if this correct?

Comment: With the use of Karnaugh map I have found $x_2\lor x_1x_3.$

Comment: Do we get the same minimal form using Quine-McCluskey method and using the Karnaugh map? Are these two methods equivalent? @user376343

Comment: I checked ... we have the same function, but my form is minimal. I am not familiar with the Q-MC method, so I don´t know if there are further constraints. What I know is that a *minimal* form is only one for the present function.